# Alter/modify/change a MSBuild property from a command line

Tags: command-line, msbuild, command-line-arguments

Suppose I have the MSBuild script with the following property set up:

```
<PropertyGroup ...>
    <DCC_Define>DEBUG;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
```

I want to build my project from a command-line, but add an additional symbol to that property. For example, I want to add `TEST`, so the property's value would be `TEST;DEBUG` or `DEBUG;TEST`.

What is a good way of doing so?

For example, I could run:

```
msbuild ... /p:DCC_Define="TEST"
```

but that would override (e.g. replace) the property value. So the final value would be just `TEST`.

Attempt to run like this:

```
msbuild ... /p:DCC_Define="TEST;$(DCC_Define)"
```

does not help: the `TEST` symbol is present, while the `DEBUG` one is not.

Any suggestions? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the _kibitz target.

```
msbuild <projectfile> /p:config=Release /target:_kibitz /p:_kibitztask="EvaluateProperty" /p:_EvaluateName="DCC_Define" /NoLogo /verbosity:normal
```

This would result in output like:

```
Der Buildvorgang wurde am 09.06.2022 12:00:46 gestartet. 
Projekt"<Projectfile>" auf Knoten "1", _kibitz Ziel(e).
_EvaluateProperty:   EvaluateProperty=RELEASE;;FRAMEWORK_VCL
Die Erstellung des Projekts "<projectfile>" ist abgeschlossen, _kibitz Ziel(e).
```

You could then parse the _EvaluateProperty line to retrieve the value. This value can then be used for a subsequent call.